# python dictionary error is occurring

Tags: python, dictionary

Python dictionaries are maps. With square brackets, we assign and access a value at a key. With get() we can specify a default result.

But why this happens?

```
cu = {}
for p in soup.find_all('p'): 
    parent = p.findParent()
    if parent not in cu.keys():
        cu[parent]=[]
    cu[parent].append(p)
for key in cu.keys():
    bolok = '<div class="test">'
    for block in cu[key]: 
        bolok += str(block)
    bolok+='</div>'
    cu[key][0].replace_with(soup.new_tag('test')) 


>> cu.keys()[0]
>> <div class="inner">\n<span class="icon major fa-cloud"></span>\n<h1>Hi, I'm <strong>Photon</strong>, another fine<br/>\r\n\t\t\t\t\tlittle freebie from <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.</h1>\n<div></div>\n<ul class="actions">\n<li><a class="button scrolly" href="#one">Discover</a></li>\n</ul>\n</div>


>> cu[cu.keys()[0]]

>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError:  <div class="inner">\n<span class="icon major fa-cloud"></span>\n<h1>Hi, I'm <strong>Photon</strong>, another fine<br/>\r\n\t\t\t\t\tlittle freebie from <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.</h1>\n<div></div>\n<ul class="actions">\n<li><a class="button scrolly" href="#one">Discover</a></li>\n</ul>\n</div>
```

Comment: This can't work in python 3. Can you provide a [mcve]. And please don't use `dict` as your variable.

Comment: Note that `dict` already means something in Python.

Comment: `dict.keys()` does not make sense. You need an instance of `dict`, which holds the method `keys()`

Comment: well dict is not actual variable name.

Comment: @SludgeDeath then you should not be putting it in this fashion. Its misleading

Comment: @SludgeDeath Well what is it then?

Comment: which python version are you using. check the following example with python 2. `cu = {"""<div class="inner">\n<span class="icon major fa-cloud"></span>\n<h1>Hi, I'm <strong>Photon</strong>, another fine<br/>\r\n\t\t\t\t\tlittle freebie from <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.</h1>\n<div></div>\n<ul class="actions">\n<li><a class="button scrolly" href="#one">Discover</a></li>\n</ul>\n</div>""":1}
cu[cu.keys()[0]]`

Comment: it works. i'm using python 2.7.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason for this to happen

```
>>> d={'uu':55}
>>> d[d.keys()[0]]
55
```

Unless you (unintentionally) modified your dict meanwhile

**EDIT**
Thanks for editing your question.

First of you should use a `defaultdict`, you won't have to initialize the empty list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
cu = defaultdict(list)
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    parent = p.findParent()
    cu[parent].append(p)
```

Then don't iterate over keys if you don't need them, try `values`:

```
for blocks in cu.values():
    bolok = '<div class="test">'
    for block in blocks: 
        bolok += str(block)
    bolok += '</div>'
    blocks[0].replace_with(soup.new_tag('test'))
```

Comment: excatly, but it does.those strings are actually bs4 objects. key is parent element, and value is child element. maybe something to do with encoding or something?

Comment: It's worth noting that `d.keys()[0]` does not work in Python 3, as dictionary views do not support indexing

Comment: OK so the keys are not strings but BeautifulSoup objects ? Can you show me a sample of how you construct the dict ?

Comment: @SludgeDeath I updated my answer, what does the last line do (replace_with) ?

Comment: @SludgeDeath I tried many times but I couldn't reproduce your error, try debugging and print cu, cu[key][0] and cu.keys()[0] after every loop you will see better. Glad my solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

which python version are you using. check the following example with python 2.

```
cu = {"""<div class="inner">\n<span class="icon major fa-cloud"></span>\n<h1>Hi, I'm <strong>Photon</strong>, another fine<br/>\r\n\t\t\t\t\tlittle freebie from <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.</h1>\n<div></div>\n<ul class="actions">\n<li><a class="button scrolly" href="#one">Discover</a></li>\n</ul>\n</div>""":1} 
cu[cu.keys()[0]]
```